# Привязка .exe к медиафайлу

Tags: exe, видео, аудио

Можно ли привязать *.exe файл к какому-ибудь медиафайлу (например, к аудиозаписи или к видео), чтобы при открытии этого медиафайла запускался и этот .exe файл?

Comment: А командные файлы и ярлыки не годятся, да?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, например:

1. Пишите примитивный медиаплеер (youtube.com + make basic media player), который будет при запуске (извиняюсь за тавтологию), запускать ещё несколько (дочерних) процессов.
2. Ассоциируете свой плеер с нужным типом файла в системе
3. ...
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Это не возможно, если, конечно, в программе не существует ошибка, дающая возможность использования `exploita-a`. Можно посмотреть на `exploit-db.com`.

Comment: С чего бы это было невозможно? Вы когда открываете вордовский документ у вас же winword.exe запускается, не так ли?

PS. Я, конечно, подразумеваю, что ТС хочет завязаться на тип файла, а не на конкретный файл.

Comment: wnword.exe запускается, потому что он является транслятором для файлов, которые ассоциированы с ним.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?